# Constant Bias in Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/blob/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/mnist_3.1_convolutional_bigger_dropout.py) example of a CNN implemented in Tensorflow.

In this example of a CNN the bias is constant (starting from line 59).

```
58 W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6, 6, 1, K], stddev=0.1))
59 B1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [K]))
60 W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, K, L], stddev=0.1))
61 B2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [L]))
62 W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, L, M], stddev=0.1))
63 B3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [M]))
```

Does that mean that the optimizer does not adjust the bias? If yes, what's the reason for a constant bias? Why is the bias even in the fully connected part of the network constant?

Comment: If you provide more detailed questions maybe I could answer them.

Comment: @IgnacioPeletier I added the code. The biases `B1` - `B3` are defined as constant. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> B1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [K]))

Here B1(a variable ) is created that is initialized using a constant.
The optimizer changes the variables B1, B2, B3 during training. It is just that they were initialized with a constant. Did you see the difference?

In C/C++ this would be similar to:

```
const float c = 0.1;
float B1 = c;
float W1 = 0.2; // initialized weights
float X= 10;
float out = X*W1 + B1;
std::cout << "ouput =, " << out << " B1 =" <<B1 <<"\n";
// now update bias, weight 
B1 = B1 + B1/10;
W1 = W1 + W1/10;
out = X*W1 + B1;
std::cout << "ouput =, " << out << " B1 =" <<B1 <<"\n";
```

This is exactly what is happening. **Initializing the Variable B1 with constant C does not change the fact that B1 is still a variable.** It was just the author decision in the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/blob/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/mnist_3.1_convolutional_bigger_dropout.py) that you cited.

Answer (score 0):

The bias will change as the network is trained. It is just inizialitining at that value. Bias is very important in the fully connected networks, it is a value that will always be there not depeding on the input, and networks perform better with it.

Comment: Does the bias really change if it is a constant as mentioned in my question?

Comment: It wont change as it is a constant and it will be saved as that value in the graph. Trainable variables will change through the training process.

Answer (score 0):

A bias in a neural network works exactly the same way it does in a linear equation:

`y = mx + c`

it shifts the output by a value. As the example is using ReLU as the activation, any negative gradient won't propagate through it. Adding a bias allows more gradient values to propagate through.

Usually bias is initialized as zeros and can be set to be trainable or not. But in this example they've initialized it as constant 0.1, which would not be trainable.

Bias initialization is not extremely important in training as compared to the Weight Initialization.

Comment: What is the reason for a constant bias? Why does it make sense to have a constant bias if performance is not important?

Comment: The initialization of your kernel is a truncated_normal, which is basically a normal distribution with only the right side of the bell curve. So your kernel is positive and your inputs are also positive as the images are grayscale between 0 to 1. Now depending on your loss function you may get a negative gradient propogating through your network, but as the stddev of your normal is 0.1 and the learning rate is pretty small, the gradient propogating back might sometimes be a small negative value. To accomodate for it, the constant bias is added. This is sort of a fail-safe mechanism for it.